# directx 12 Unordered Access View with counters

Tags: directx, directx-12

I was writing my renderer but I run into some kind of problem. Is D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_UAV type of root parameter does not support UAVs with counters? That seems so, because I wanted root parameter with this type and not descriptor_table, but that seems UAV with counter only support if root parameter is descriptor table. Is this true? I am asking because I haven't found any specific info about this in documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quote from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/using-descriptors-directly-in-the-root-signature):

"A UAV in the root cannot have counters associated with it."